# Unable to redirect on other other page giving MultiValueDictKeyError Django

Tags: html, python-3.x, django

I am working on one simple student management system in which i am providing different options like add student, display student, display all students etc.

so first i tired to render all those functions with simple text html it works perfectly.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'csvcrud/home.html')

def add(request):
    return render(request, 'csvcrud/add.html')

def display(request):
    return render(request, 'csvcrud/display.html')

def displayall(request):
    return render(request, 'csvcrud/displayall.html')
```

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap 4 Website Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" style="margin-top:30px">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2 class="text-center">Options</h2>
       <a role="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="{% url 'csvcrud-add' %}">Add Student</a>
       <a role="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="{% url 'csvcrud-display' %}">Display Student</a> 
       <a role="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="{% url 'csvcrud-displayall' %}">Display All</a>
       <a role="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="{% url 'csvcrud-add' %}">Download CSV</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 border border-secondary rounded">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="jumbotron text-center" style="margin-bottom:0">
  <p>Footer</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

add.html

```
{% extends "csvcrud/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h2 class="text-center">Add Students</h2>
    <form action="/add" method="get" name="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="sid">Student ID</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sid" placeholder="Enter Student ID" name="sid">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="sname">Student Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sname" placeholder="Enter Student Name" name="sname">
        </div>

        <label for="gender">Gender</label>

        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="male" value="male" name="gender">Male
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="female" value="female" name="gender">Female
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="dob">Date Of Birth</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="date" value="2011-08-19" name="dob" id="dob">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="city">City</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" placeholder="Enter City" name="city">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="state">State</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="state" placeholder="Enter State" name="state">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email ID</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="quali">Qualification</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quali" placeholder="Enter Qualification" name="quali">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="stream">Stream</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="stream" placeholder="Enter stream" name="stream">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        <br><br>
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

after that i want to add all those form input data in students.csv. so for that i used `request.GET[]` method and then print all the added info in `printt.html`

here is updated view file
views.html

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import csv
from csv import writer

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'csvcrud/home.html')

def add(request):
    
    if request.method == "GET":
        sid = request.GET['sid']
        sname = request.GET['sname']
        gender = request.GET['gender']
        dob = request.GET['dob']
        city = request.GET['city']
        state = request.GET['state']
        email = request.GET['email']
        quali = request.GET['quali']
        stream = request.GET['stream']

        alist = [sid, sname, gender, dob, city, state, email, quali, stream ]
        print(alist)
        # Open file in append mode
        with open('students.csv', 'a+', newline='') as write_obj:
            # Create a writer object from csv module
            csv_writer = writer(write_obj)
            # Add contents of list as last row in the csv file
            csv_writer.writerow(alist)
        print("Added Successfully!!!")

        flist = []
        flist.append({'sid':sid})
        flist.append({'sname':sname})
        flist.append({'gender':gender})
        flist.append({'dob':dob})
        flist.append({'city':city})
        flist.append({'state':state})
        flist.append({'email':email})
        flist.append({'quali':quali})
        flist.append({'stream':stream})

        return render(request, 'csvcrud/printt.html', {"flist": flist})

def display(request):
    return render(request, 'csvcrud/display.html')

def displayall(request):
    return render(request, 'csvcrud/displayall.html')
```

printt.html

```
{% extends "csvcrud/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% for file in flist %}
    {{ file }}
    <br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

So when i tried to access above code individualy it works fine but when i tried to access it from add button it gives me an error.
[image]

Comment: try using `request.GET.get('sid')`.

Comment: hey man it works but the problem is it shows result of submitted form but i want to show my form so that user can fill it and then submit it